# Looping circles with specific functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, shapes, turtle-graphics

***Answered***

I need to create a function named "caterpillar()", this function is used to join my draw_circle() function, and draw_line() functions together to create a caterpullar. I'm stuck on trying to create the three circles needed for the caterpillars body using draw_circle within a while loop. This is all my code so far:

```
from turtle import *
import turtle


def moveto(x,y):
    penup()
    goto(x,y)
    pendown()




def draw_circle(xpos,ypos,radius,colour):
    moveto(xpos,ypos)
    circle(radius)
    turtle.fillcolor(colour)

def draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
goto(x2,y2)

def draw_square(x,y,length,colour):
    moveto(x,y)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    turtle.fillcolor(colour)



def caterpillar():
    draw_line(0,30,-20,-15) # feelers
    draw_line(0,30,20,-15) # feelers
    draw_line(60,30,40,-15) # feelers
    draw_line(60,30,80,-15) # feelers
    draw_line(120,30,100,-15) # feelers
    draw_line(120,30,140,-15) # feelers


    for _ in range(3) : # 3 body circles
        xpos = 0
        ypos = 0
        radius = 30
        turtle.begin_fill()
        draw_circle(0,0,30,"green")
        turtle.end_fill()
        xpos = xpos + (radius*2)



caterpillar()
```

I am stuck on the last part under "for _ in range(3)" - I need to loop three circles using the draw_circle function at these specific coords:
[Caterpillar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUmAZ.png)

I've been stuck on this for hours, any help would be much appreciated!
Edit:
Also forgot to mention, that i keep getting the error "File "C:\Users\Rekesh\Desktop\caterpillar\1.py", line 48, in caterpillar
    xpos = xpos +(radius*2)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xpos' referenced before assignment
When I use xpos = xpos, i'm not sure if this is needed.

Comment: `radius` is set to 30, and never gets updated. So you end up in an infinite loop. Perhaps radius is not the correct condition, and you are interested in the number of circles you want to make.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal If you're meaning why I put a radius inside the draw_circle() function, that's because it's mean't to be like that. I've been stuck on this for hours, and just cannot figure out how to do a loop of 3 circles using my functions. Almost to the point of where I want to pay someone to help me haha.

Comment: I meant, radius is used in caterpillar as a `while` condition, but never updated. Radius always remains 30. What happens if you replace `while  radius > .1:` with `for _ in range(3):`?

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal Okay, thank you for that, just found out that using 'for _ in range(3):' doesn't set it as an infinite loop. Now what it does, is creates a circle in the same place (0, 0), but only 3 times. Now i just need it to move across to the right, with the same coords as the image i posted.

Comment: You need to make `xpos` local to the `caterpillar` function so you can update it inside the function. So just move `xpos = 0` into the function; you might as well move those `ypos = 0` and `radius = 30` statements too.

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay, i've just done that and that removed the error i was getting. But it's still creating the circles in one coord, i'm wanting it to move x = 60 for the second circle then x = 120 for the third circle, i thought `xpos = xpos + (r*2)` would work since it has in the past for other programs, but it's not.

Comment: What's `r`? I assume it has a value of zero, or your program would throw an error. `xpos = xpos + radius*2` should work if you defined `xpos` and `radius` properly. BTW, if you want `draw_circle` to draw coloured circles you need to change it. Get rid of `turtle.fillcolor(colour)` and put `turtle.color(colour)` on the line before `circle(radius)`. FWIW, using both the "colour" and "color" spellings in a program can be confusing, and it's so easy to accidentally type the wrong one.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh sorry, it was actually `xpos = pos + (radius*2)`. And it still does work fine with `turtle.fillcolor(colour)`, i just need to enter `turtle.being_fill()` and `turtle.end_fill()` to make it work. It's still not working which is very strange, here are my settings: `xpos = 0`, `ypos = 0`, `radius = 30`. What i would think is that it calculates the x coords by multiplying the radius, so the x coord is 60 for the second circle, but it still stays at 0, and just draws three circles at the exact same coord being (0, 0)

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing wrong. Using ShashankAgarwal's `for` loop I get 3 circles, with the x coord updated as expected.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've updated the code at the top with exactly what I have now, could you please try and compare that to yours that is working

Comment: Those `xpos = 0`, `ypos = 0`, `radius = 30` statements need to be inside `caterpillar` but **before** the `for` loop. By placing them inside the loop those variables get re-set on every loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring that worked! - thank you! :), and ShashankAgarwal thank you too for providing me with the needed for loop :) (Not sure on how to give reputation to both of you :P)

Comment: Well, we can't get rep because neither of us wrote an actual answer. :)